# How do we get Lightning to pass errors to the console rather than the "Look's like there's a problem:" dialog?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, debugging

I've followed the steps [from Trailhead](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/force_com_dev_intermediate/lightning_components/lightning_components_debug), however when I have errors outside of my own components I get this unhelpful dialog. Is there something I'm missing to get a normal console error?

[image: Look's like there's a problem:]

Comment: Haven't tried this myself yet but they have a new inspector... https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc

Comment: I've used the new inspector a lot. It's really good at figuring out rendering issues, performance, event tracking and actions... but not so much on errors.

This particular issue I found the root cause was calling a deleted APEX method, but I only got there through reviewing my changes in source control over the past 3 days... if this error came to the console and I could see have seen it in context it would have been so much simpler :)

Comment: Interesting - this is the first time I've heard of this specific issue - I'm opening a bug to track improving the error message for this. Were you running with LC Development mode enabled?

Comment: [As far as I can tell.](https://imgur.com/KTWpNUk)